# Conditionally build a Google Datastore query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-datastore

How would I go about programmatically constructing a google datastore query? I am trying to build a filter based on params from a form inside a Rails app.

Using the example from googles docs:

```
query = datastore.query("Task")
             .where("done", "=", false)
             .where("priority", ">=", 4)
             .order("priority", :desc)
```

If wanted to change this so that 'done' will include both true & false values, I have tried variations of this with no joy:

```
query = datastore.query("Task")
         .where("done", "=", false) unless params['done'] == 'ALL'
         .where("priority", ">=", 4)
         .order("priority", :desc)
```

I need to be able to do this for all where clauses.

Answer (score 0):

As datastore doesn't support the OR operator, you will have to perform multiple queries and then combine the results.

One that checks for .where("done", "=", false) and the other .where("done", "=", true)